# Returning a mutable reference in Rust

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust, so apologies if this is a trivial question. I have googled for an hour to no avail.

I have an array of enum values. I wish to find a random location within that array that matches a specific pattern and return a mutable reference to it, with the intent of modifying the element in that location.

```
enum Tile {
    Empty,
    ...  // Other enum values
}

fn random_empty_tile(arr: &mut [Tile]) -> &mut Tile {
    loop {
        let i = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, arr.len());
        let tile = &mut arr[i];
        if let Tile::Empty = tile {
            return tile;
        }
    }
}
```

The borrow checker complains about two specific things here. The first is the `arr.len()` call. This is disallowed because it requires taking an immutable reference to `arr`, and we already have a mutable reference to `arr` via the parameter. Therefore, no other references can be taken and the call is not allowed.

The second is `return tile`. This fails because the borrow checker cannot prove that the lifetime of this reference is the same as the lifetime of `arr` itself, so it's not safe to be returned.

I think the above descriptions of the errors are correct; I think I understand what is going wrong. Unfortunately I have no idea how to fix either of these problems. If someone could provide an idiomatic solution to achieve this behaviour, it would be greatly appreciated.

Ultimately, I wish to do the following:

```
let mut arr = [whatever];
let empty_element = random_empty_tile(&mut arr);
*empty_element = Tile::SomeOtherValue;
```

Thus mutating the array such that the empty value is replaced.

Comment: Here is a working version: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aeb42c30f113d560235b8e6d6897f9b4. However it seems strange why does the borrow checker fails here if we add `let tile = &mut arr[i];` as an intermediate variable. Is this a shortcoming of the compiler ?

Comment: @Psidom Yes, this is a known shortcoming of the borrow checker.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Answer to the problem**

```
fn random_empty_tile(arr: &mut [Tile]) -> &mut Tile {
    let len = arr.len();
    let mut the_chosen_i = 0;
    loop {
        let i = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, len);
        let tile = &mut arr[i];
        if let Tile::Empty = tile {
            the_chosen_i = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    &mut arr[the_chosen_i]
}
```

will work. You are allowed to use a mutable borrow in the loop, just don't *abuse* it, from the borrowcheckers perpective. What you're effectively doing, is mutably re-borrowing an array repeatedly. As always, the compiler is super helpful, if you know how to use it.

To get to the root of the problem, lets look at just the first two iterations of our loop:

```
fn random_empty_tile_2<'arr>(arr: &'arr mut [Tile]) -> &'arr mut Tile {
   let len = arr.len();

   // First loop iteration
   {
       let i = thread_rng().gen_range(0, len);
       let tile = &mut arr[i]; // Lifetime: 'arr
       if let Tile::Empty = tile {
           return tile;
       }
   } 

   // Second loop iteration
   {
       let i = thread_rng().gen_range(0, len);
       let tile = &mut arr[i]; // Lifetime: 'arr
        if let Tile::Empty = tile {
           return tile;
       }
   }

   unreachable!();
```

}

The compiler tells us: The borrow of `arr`, called `tile` has to have the same lifetime as the array itself, called `'arr`, as it is returned. In the next loop iteration, we again borrow `arr` for `'arr`. This is a violation of the borrowcheckers rules.

**Some comments**

Your're not doing yourself a favor with all this mutability. This might manifest in the borrowchecker complaining later on in main, when you try to hold a mutable reference to a value in `arr` and use `arr` at the same time, as this is (of course, if you think about it!) disallowed.

Also, your algorithm for choosing a random empty tile is dangerously speculative. What if there's only one empty tile in a large array? Your implementation will take forever. Consider first filtering to all indices pointing to an empty tile, then choose a random index from this set, then return the entry this index points to. I wont provide code for this, you got this on your own :)

Comment: Isn't the local variable `tile` out of scope after each iteration? Why is it brought down to the next iteration by the borrow checker ?

Comment: You would thinks so! But `tile` going out of scope doesn't change that it is returned by the function. It needs to have lifetime less than or equal to `arr`, outliving is forbidden. You can indeed annotate as `let tile : &'arr mut Tile = ...`. You cant have mutiple mutable borrows of the same thing, with the same lifetime.

Comment: *You cant have multiple mutable borrows of the same thing, with the same lifetime*. Shouldn't this be *you can't have multiple mutable borrows of the same thing **at the same time***. Basically if the borrow reaches the end of its own scope, we can borrow it again. Regarding the return statement, once the function is returned, we will have no next iteration anymore. Why would it continue to check in the next iteration ?

Comment: You are right in that the existence of `tile_1, tile_2, ...` is mutually exclusive- at least to me it seems like it. But the compiler cant figure this out (yet, possibly?). We could employ a `RefCell` here, to see if this actually holds at runtime, then if we are sure and have prooven it, `unsafe`. If you wanted to hear that: You are right :)

Comment: Of course I wouldn't actually advocate this. This code IMO is highly unidiomatic, and more idiomatic versions also pass the compiler without any problem, without the need for interior mutability.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Are you saying that the compiler extends the scope of whatever is returned to the end of the function regardless of the scope defined by the `loop` here ?

Comment: In this specific case, the compiler has to check all the lifetimes against each other. It sees they conflict and cant prove they are not mutually exclusive, as you pointed out. It cant deduct each borrow only lasts for a unique iteration of the loop- after all, whats stopping you from assigning to an outer `&'arr mut Tile`? The point is that you know you dont, but this is a complex problem. Don't quote me on all this though- I am by no means a rust compiler guy.